# Is there an easier way to specify javadoc urls in intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc, ivy

I have multiple modules in an IntelliJ project where each module's dependencies are managed by ivy.

My problem is that for every single module, I have to specify the javadoc url of common 3rd party libraries through these tedious actions:

1. Pick up the mouse
2. Find the library's javadoc in google
3. Right click on the module and select Module Settings
4. Go to the Dependencies tab
5. Click on the correct module library

   - All modules have their dependencies pulled to their own jar directories through ivy, so combining common libraries into a project-level library is not an option
6. Click Edit
7. Click Specify documentation URL
8. Paste the url
9. Click 3 OK's
10. Hit Ctrl+Q and see if it worked.

    - If it didn't work because I pasted the wrong url or used the wrong library, repeat.

Having to do this for every single module for commons-lang, commons-collections, hibernate, spring, etc gets very tedious. Is there a way to specify a global list of fallback javadoc urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Maven, IDEA can fetch sources and javadocs automatically from Maven and configure the project with zero clicks.

Another option would be writing custom ivy plug-in which will do the same or modify one of the existing ivy plug-ins.

Comment: I haven't worked out all the details yet, but I think using ivy to set stuff up correctly is the way to go. Thanks!